# Mongoose increment or decrement using schema.post is not decrementing

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to increase or decrease the number of ads of a user. I can increment the number but I can't decrement it.

```
const updateUserAdsNumber = (saveOrDelete) => {
finalSchema.post(saveOrDelete, (ad, next) => {
    const increaseOrDecrease = saveOrDelete === 'save' ? 1 : -1;

    User.findOneAndUpdate(
        {_id: ad.adInfo.userId},
        {$inc: {adsPublished: increaseOrDecrease}},
        (err, user) => {
            if (err) return console.error('User ads could not increase or decrease', err.message);
        }
    );
    next();
 });
};

 updateUserAdsNumber('save');
 updateUserAdsNumber('deleteOne');

 finalSchema.plugin(mongooseUniqueValidator);

 const AdModel = mongoose.model('Ad', finalSchema);
```

Here's the route that deletes the ad:

```
router.delete('/:id', verifyTokenMiddleware, (req, res) => {
const id = req.params.id;
const {tokenDecoded} = req;
Ad.deleteOne({'adInfo.userId': tokenDecoded.userId, _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id)}, (err) => {
    if(err){
        res.status(400).send({
            message: 'The ad could not be deleted. (Error_message = ' + err.message + ')'
        });
    } else {
        res.send({
            message: 'Ad deleted successfully!'
        })
    }
  })
});
```

I'm using `mongoose@5.2.13` and `Mongo 3.6.5`, what might go wrong? I could put the logic directly into router.delete but I prefer to hook it before schema export.

Comment: Could you try with this instead const increaseOrDecrease = saveOrDelete !== 'save' ? -1 : 1; some times it works for me.

Comment: thanks for the comment, this won't work either. It seems that `updateUserAdsNumber('deleteOne')` is being ignored when deleting the ad and I can't figure out why. I also tried with `remove` (i changed the route to `Ad.remove()` too but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in documentation of mongoose I should update the document, not the collection. So, instead of:

```
router.delete('/:id', verifyTokenMiddleware, (req, res) => {
const id = req.params.id;
const {tokenDecoded} = req;
Ad.deleteOne({'adInfo.userId': tokenDecoded.userId, _id: 
mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id)}, (err) => {
if(err){
    res.status(400).send({
        message: 'The ad could not be deleted. (Error_message = ' + err.message + ')'
    });
} else {
    res.send({
        message: 'Ad deleted successfully!'
    })
   }
 })
});
```

I used this:

```
router.delete('/:id', verifyTokenMiddleware, (req, res) => {
const id = req.params.id;
const {tokenDecoded} = req;
Ad.findById({'adInfo.userId': tokenDecoded.userId, _id: 
mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id)}, (err, ad) => {
    if (err) {
        res.status(500).send({
            message: 'The ad could not be deleted. (Error_message = ' + 
 err.message + ')'
        });
    } else {
        ad.remove(err => {    <---- here's the document remove
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
        res.send({
            message: 'Ad deleted successfully!'
        });
    }
  });
});
```

and switched from `updateUserAdsNumber('deleteOne')` to  `updateUserAdsNumber('remove')` in the first method above (in the question) and everything works as expected.